# Low-profile clear cover for a basement window

Tags: windows, maintenance

I'm looking to protect some wooden exterior basement window casing so that I don't have to re-paint it so regularly.

I've seen window well covers like so:

[image: window well cover]

...which could be useful except that this particular window is right next to a sidewalk that I walk by and drag garbage cans on frequently, so something that sticks out more than 6" or so from the wall will be an obstruction.

I searched for low profile window well covers, and I've found things like:

[image: low profile window well cover]

...which is low-profile in the wrong direction (low to the ground).

What is an easy solution that will not stick out far from the wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a search for shutter caps.  These are metal caps that go over the tops of shutters.  They will help with the top, but not likely the splash-back from the ground.  If you can find a roofer or a siding contractor with a sheet metal brake (and is willing to deal with a small project) you could easily bend a strip of metal, perhaps 3 or 4 inches wide, to create a narrow shed roof/awning over the window to direct the water away.  You can lap it under the siding if you have siding or adhesive and caulk if you have brick.  You might even find a suitable piece of "L" flashing, valley flashing or drip edge that might work at the local building supply or lumber yard.